# If blank return 0 else run vlookup

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I would like to use the vlookup function to match two criteria values firstly based on the value selected in a dropdown menu (country) and the value in A2(name). If the value in A2 Sheet matches the one of the values in the A column in Sheet2 and the value of the dropdown menu in Sheet1 matches one of the values in Sheet2 Column D (Which is a concatenation of the name and country) I would like to return the corresponding value in Sheet2 ColumnC.

If the value is 0 or blank I would like to return 0.

This is what I have tried

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(
   ISBLANK(
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$E$61,3,1),"0"))))
```

Not sure what I might  be doing wrong

Here is a sample of my data

Sheet 1:

```
A           B             C        
name1      (vlookup)    [dropdownmenu]
```

and Sheet 2

```
A                 B                    C
name1            val                   concatenationofA&B
```

Here is a test sheet as requested:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsFnaGY7N9nXyPs5vR32jG5G838w1SgB2XIad7bEFXg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @lurker thanks, noted and edited

Comment: @lurker that's a typo, editing that now

Comment: Please share a test sheet.

Comment: @marikamitsos I have included a test sheet

Comment: It is private :(

Comment: @marikamitsos sorry about that, please try it now

Comment: Is any of your columns sorted? If so, which one?

Comment: @marikamitsos no sorted columns

Comment: You were using `1` as the 3rd parameter in your `VLOOKUP` which means sorted first column. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&C2:C, {Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B, Sheet2!C2:C}, 2, 0), 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this using the query function

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!$A$2:$E$61,"select C where B = """&C12&""" and A = """&A12&""" ")
```

The only problem is I don't know how to suppress NA values/replace them with the value 0

Comment: Does this work for you? I believe that the answer by player0 would be a better pick.